# Creating custom column for week number of a column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I have a df such as

```
  Date     | User 
2019-08-05   Bob
2019-07-01   Chris
2019-08-13   Bob
2019-08-20   Chris
2019-09-24   Bob
```

Expected output

```
  Date     | User  | Week_number
2019-08-05   Bob         1
2019-07-01   Chris       1
2019-08-13   Bob         2
2019-08-20   Chris       9
2019-09-24   Bob         8
```

How can I create a new column that would give me the week # of that date range?
(the week # for user would be the # in where the first date would be under week 1

in the past I have used methods such as `df['Date'].dt.day` and then used that to cut bins but this is different where I am assigning week number based on that users custom range

Thanks for taking time to read my post

Comment: Your input and your output dataframes do not contain the same dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean how many weeks have passed since the first date of the user:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df['WeekNumber'] = df.Date.groupby(df.User).diff().dt.days.fillna(0).astype(int) // 7 + 1

df

        Date   User  WeekNumber
0 2019-08-05    Bob           1
1 2019-07-01  Chris           1
2 2019-08-13    Bob           2
3 2019-08-20  Chris           8
4 2019-09-24    Bob           7
```

Answer (score 1):

Difference between weeks even if the first date is not on Monday:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['WeekNumber'] = df.groupby('User')['Date'] \
                     .apply(lambda x: 1 + x.dt.isocalendar().week
                                      - min(x.dt.isocalendar().week))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        Date   User  WeekNumber
0 2019-08-05    Bob           1
1 2019-07-01  Chris           1
2 2019-08-13    Bob           2
3 2019-08-20  Chris           8
4 2019-09-24    Bob           8
```

Comment: Thought the same. Code: `df['Date'] =pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%W').astype(int)
df['WeekNumber'] = df.groupby('User')['Date'].transform(lambda x: (x-x.min())+1)
print(df)`